# Which USB device class/sub is used to define a USB token/dongle

Tags: usb, driver, access-token

I'm writing a driver for a custom **HSM** (**USB Token**). I need to know which USB class/subclass is the appropriate one for me. According to USB.org, here are a couple of them, that (*by name*) seem to be related:

- Content Security Method 2 - USB Digital Transmission Content Protection Implementation 1.0
- Device Class Definition for Content Security Devices 2.0
- Smart Card CCID version 1.1
- Smart Card ICCD version 1.0

Help, anyone?